# Bringing and housing cats to Thailand?

Tags: thailand, pets

I plan to teach in Thailand for 6-18 months and I have two adult cats I would like to bring with from the U.S. Is this a common and accepted practice? Will there be any issues with customs or housing?

Comment: If you can read Thai follow the link on this page: http://www.thaiembassy.ca/en/visiting-thailand/bringing-pets-thailand

Comment: Thanks but that link seems to be broken and sadly I cannot read thai.

Comment: Sorry that one: http://www.dld.go.th/

Comment: note that the airline you choose to use for your cats may have separate rules (In some places - no travel during summer months, size of crates, and more).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [page](http://www.thaiembassy.org/pretoria/en/business/29701-Importation-of-live-animals-into-Thailand.html), here is the process to import cats or dogs in the Kingdom of Thailand:

1. A health certificate in English, signed or further endorsed by a full-time authorized veterinary official of the government of the exporting country, if it is previously acknowledged by a veterinary surgeon, stating: (a) number and species, (b) breed, sex, age and color or animal identification, (c) name and address of the owner OR the kennel of origin, (d) certification of condition items (2) to (5).
2. The animals must come from an area where animal diseases are under control. They must be healthy, free from signs of any infectious and contagious diseases including ectoparasitism at the time of export and fit to travel.
3. The country must be Rabies-free for at least the past 12 (twelve) months OR the animals are vaccinated against Rabies with an official approved vaccine not less than 21 (twenty- one) days prior to the departure.
4. EITHER a) The dog is vaccinated against Leptospirosis at least 21(twenty-one) days preceding departure.
   OR b) The dog is subjected to a test for Leptospirosis with negative result during the 30 (thirty) days prior to the departure.
5. The animals shall be vaccinated against other significant infectious or contagious diseases i.e. Distemper, Hepatitis, and Parvovirus, with an official approved vaccine at least 21 (twenty-one) days prior to the departure.
6. The animals must be transported in nose-and-paw proof crates designed to avoid any risk of injury or unnecessary suffering.
7. The animals are not allowed to be exposed to other animals if they have to be landed in transit at any approved intermediate port. They shall not be allowed to leave precinct of the port except to an officially approved transit quarantine area.
8. The animals are subjected to quarantine at approved premises for a period of at least 30 (thirty) days upon arrival during which they shall be submitted to tests and/or treatments as may be deemed necessary. The importer/owner shall be fully charged for the incurred expenses.
9. Failure to follow the import procedures may result in returning the animals to the country of origin or destroying without compensation.